# Create hash inside loop with query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a hash from data which are pulled out from db. The hash should looks like

```
hash { id: process.id,
       name: company_name }
```

To get company_name I have to do some query which returns an array of strings with company names:

```
Process.all.map do |process|
  process.inquiry_field_responses
         .joins(:inquiry_field)
         .where(inquiry_fields: { name: 'company_name' })
         .first&.value
end
```

To create this hash I thought all I should do is something like:

```
fetcher = []

Process.all.map do |process|
  company_name = process.inquiry_field_responses
                        .joins(:inquiry_field)
                        .where(inquiry_fields: { name: 'company_name' })
                        .first&.value
  if company_name != nil
    fetcher << {
      id: process.id,
      name: company_name,
    }
  end
end
```

But in the result I've:

```
    2.6.0 :318 > fetcher
 => [{:id=>1, :name=>nil}, {:id=>2, :name=>nil}, {:id=>3, :name=>nil}, 
{:id=>4, :name=>nil}, {:id=>5, :name=>nil}, {:id=>6, :name=>nil}, {:id=>7, 
:name=>nil}, {:id=>8, :name=>nil}, {:id=>9, :name=>nil}, {:id=>10, 
:name=>nil}, {:id=>11, :name=>nil}, {:id=>12, :name=>nil}, {:id=>13, 
:name=>nil}, {:id=>14, :name=>nil}, {:id=>15, :name=>nil}, {:id=>16, 
:name=>nil}, {:id=>17, :name=>nil}, {:id=>18, :name=>nil}, {:id=>19, 
:name=>nil}, {:id=>20, :name=>nil}, {:id=>21, :name=>nil}, {:id=>22, 
:name=>nil}, {:id=>23, :name=>nil}, {:id=>24, :name=>nil}, {:id=>25, 
:name=>nil}, {:id=>26, :name=>nil}, {:id=>27, :name=>nil}, {:id=>28, 
:name=>nil}, {:id=>29, :name=>nil}, {:id=>30, :name=>nil}, {:id=>31, 
:name=>nil}, {:id=>32, :name=>nil}, {:id=>33, :name=>nil}, {:id=>34, 
:name=>nil}, {:id=>35, :name=>nil}, {:id=>36, :name=>nil}, {:id=>37, 
:name=>nil}, {:id=>38, :name=>nil}, {:id=>39, :name=>nil}, {:id=>40, 
:name=>nil}, {:id=>41, :name=>nil}, {:id=>42, :name=>nil}, {:id=>43, 
:name=>nil}, {:id=>44, :name=>nil}, {:id=>45, :name=>nil}, {:id=>46, 
:name=>nil}, {:id=>47, :name=>nil}, {:id=>48, :name=>nil}, {:id=>49, 
:name=>nil}, {:id=>50, :name=>nil}, {:id=>51, :name=>"231421AAAAA firma"}, 
{:id=>52, :name=>"tregfsd"}, {:id=>53, :name=>"aaaaa"}, {:id=>54, 
:name=>"zzzzzz"}, {:id=>55, :name=>"bbbbb"},
```

Instead of:

```
2.6.0 :318 > fetcher
{:id=>52, :name=>"tregfsd"}, {:id=>53, :name=>"aaaaa"}, {:id=>54, 
:name=>"zzzzzz"}, {:id=>55, :name=>"bbbbb"},
```

Comment: Are you sure that giving yourself a N+1 query issue is really the answer here? Can you instead provide an example of the data and the desired output? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: `if company_name.present?` will check also check if `company_name` might be an empty string

Comment: @max updated, is it what you wanted?

Comment: @lacostenycoder ok but now instead of `id: 1, name: nil` I've got an array with nil values at the front and then hashes with some data - `=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, [{:id=>52, :name=>"tregfsd"}, {:id=>53, :name=>"aaaaa"}]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of iteration will need to be optimized to avoid N+1 query problem on large data sets.  But this will probably work for you for now.

```
Process.all.map do |process|
  company_name = process.inquiry_field_responses
                        .joins(:inquiry_field)
                        .where(inquiry_fields: { name: 'company_name' })
                        .first&.value
  if company_name.present?
    {
      id: process.id,
      name: company_name,
    }
  end
end.compact
```

Comment: With this code I've `TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)`

Comment: try just `.compact` and omit the `.select`

Comment: I've mixed up something, it works with and without `select`. Now I've to avoid N+1 somehow.

Comment: @mr_muscle so is `.select` needed? I removed it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting the query chain from the *Process* model you could opt to start from the *InquiryField* model.

This answer assumes the following model associations:

```
# app/models/process.rb
class Process < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :inquiry_field_responses
end
```

```
# app/models/inquiry_field_response.rb
class InquiryFieldResponse < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :process
  belongs_to :inquiry_field
end
```

```
# app/models/inquiry_field.rb
class InquiryField < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :inquiry_field_responses
end
```

With the assumptions out of the way let's get to the answer.

```
inquiry_field = inquiry_field.find_by!(name: 'company_name')
inquiry_field_responses = inquiry_field.inquiry_field_responses.where.not(value: '')

fields = %i[process_id value]
labels = %i[id name]

fetcher = inquiry_field_responses.pluck(*fields).map { |data| labels.zip(data).to_h }
```

I first fetch the inquiry field that describes the field you want. From there I get the inquiry field responses without empty or `NULL` value. Get the fields you want using the [`pluck`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) method and  [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-map) the resulting array. [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-zip) the labels to the data and convert the resulting array to a hash using [`to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-to_h).